# Extjs4: How to get all selected Rows in a Grid with "multiSelect: true"

Tags: grid, extjs4, multi-select, gridpanel

I have a Grid Panel. In the Controller of this Grid I have my init function:

```
init: function() {
    var selected_vorgang={};        
    this.control({
        'provisionscheckgrid':{
            itemcontextmenu: this.itemListCtxMenu,
            select: function(s,record,row) {
                console.log(record.data.id);
                selected_vorgang[record.data.id]=record.data.free;
                console.log(selected_vorgang);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to check, which row or which rows are currently selected. Then I want to put the id of the selected row in an object or remove it, if its no more selected. Does anyone know, how to get all the selected rows to make my function?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

I have it. Had to make it over getSelectionModel().

```
var list = Ext.getCmp("myGrid").getView().getSelectionModel();
                var store = Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore();

                for(key in list.selected.items)
                {

                    var rowIndex = store.indexOf(list.selected.items[key]);
                    //Here are the selected numbers
                }
```